# Firebase + Swift Deleting Rows in TableView

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok, I was following this tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2) for deleting rows in tableView with Firebase but it just doesn't seem to work. My code as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureDatabase() 
}

func configureDatabase() {
    self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        self.ref.child("mileage").queryOrderedByChild("user").queryEqualToValue(user.uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            self.mileageDatabase.insert(snapshot, atIndex: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

        })


    } else {

    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        let row = self.mileageDatabase[indexPath.row]
        row.ref.removeValue()
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    }
}
```

It throws the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Answer (score 1):

I think that here `row.ref.removeValue()` there is a mistake. You are mixing your Array with Firebase data. If you write just:

`mileageDatabase.remove[indexPath.row]
 tableview.reloadData()`

For me is working this way. You have to capture the userkey for that row.
I have an array like yours (mileageDatabase = teste) but my variables are stored at an struct inside a sublcass (ChkList). That is the way i did it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if editingStyle == .delete {

        let user: ChkList = teste[indexPath.row]
        let uk = user.key
        print("Userkey: \(uk)")
        ref.child(uk!).removeValue()
}
}
```

This way you will have removed the data from Firebase and the row form tableview. You can see my ask where i could figure out how to fix this at: [Firebase: delete item from row (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066884/firebase-delete-item-from-row-swift-3/41105566#41105566)

Answer (score 0):

The data source still hold that object whose cell you deleted . You have to remove that object from the data source, as you delete the cell.

Comment: How do you do that!?