# Firebase: delete item from row (Swift 3)

Tags: uitableview, firebase, swift3

I have a tableview showing data from a Firebase console (JASON structure) like this:

```
chklst-xxx
     - avaliation
         -students
              -KHZAjBi44eZ8JsaswkKI
                -teacher: Paul 
                -datTime: 09.12.2016  12:25pm
                -name: Mary Anne
                -mark: 7.5 
                -preceptor: John 
              -KHWZlh7aasy78ahsiuKIi0
                -teacher: Paul 
                -datTime: 09.12.2016  12:48pm
                -name: Anne Caroline
                -mark: 9.4 
                -preceptor: Peter
```

These data are shown at a tableview, each one, after node students, except the key. I have one function to delete an especific row, as i do with other apps in CoreData (tableview editingStyle):

```
// FUNC DELETAR
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        teste.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        ref.removeValue() // HERE IS MY DOUBT
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I can erase the item from the array and from the table, but i just don't know how to do it from Firebase. I have tried other ways with removeValue, but it just didn't work, except an way to erase the whole data, not specifically that row selected.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("avaliation").child("students")
```

I need some teaching to make this works. Thank you.

Here is my method for Saving this data: (Added 09.12 19:30pm)

```
func Save(){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("avaliation").child("students").childByAutoId()
    referencia.child(“name”).setValue(Name)
    referencia.child(“teacher”).setValue(Teacher)
    referencia.child("preceptor").setValue(Preceptor)
    referencia.child("datTime”).setValue(DateTime)
    referencia.child(“mark”).setValue(ResultComFReFC)
}
```

And here is my Class where I work with the main Array:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct ChkList {
var name: String?
var teacher: String?
var preceptor: String?
var DateToday: String?
var mark: String?
var key: String!

init(name: String, teacher: String, preceptor: String, mark: String, DateToday: String, key: String = "") {
    self.name = name
    self.teacher = teacher
    self.preceptor = preceptor
    self.mark = mark
    self.DateToday = DateToday
    self.key = key
}


init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as? String
    teacher = snapshotValue["teacher"] as? String
    preceptor = snapshotValue["preceptor"] as? String
    mark = snapshotValue["mark"] as? String
    DateToday = snapshotValue["DateToday"] as? String
}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "teacher": teacher,
        "preceptor": preceptor,
        "mark": mark,
        "DateToday": DateToday   ]}}
```

UPDATE: Tableview EdityingStyle

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  if editingStyle == .delete {
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("avaliation").child("students").childByAutoId()
teste.remove(at: indexPath.row) //Array delet item
      let userKeyA = ref.key
      ref.child(userKeyA).removeValue()
      tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, using suggests above and studying and trying a lot.
The way to the method works is really capture the userkey.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if editingStyle == .delete {

        let user: ChkList = teste[indexPath.row]
        let uk = user.key
        print("Userkey: \(uk)")
        ref.child(uk!).removeValue()
}
}
```

This way you will have removed the data from Firebase and the row form tableview.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, store the `pushKey` of the user by using 'getKey' method when you `push` the user details.

```
chklst-xxx
 - avaliation
     -students
          -KHZAjBi44eZ8JsaswkKI
            -teacher: Paul 
            -userKey:KHZAjBi44eZ8JsaswkKI <--------------
            -datTime: 09.12.2016  12:25pm
            -name: Mary Anne
            -mark: 7.5 
            -preceptor: John
```

Now you can retrieve the 'key` of the user. Suppose you are listing, users in the list view and would want to delete a row.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("avaliation").child("students").child(students.getUserKey()).removeValue();
```

Let me know, if it works.

**Update:** I don't know swift. But i'll give u an abstract idea.
When you create a new student, you refer `student node` and `push()` right. Like below,

```
DatabaseReference studentsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("avaliation").child("students").push();
```

And then you put your data like,

```
studentRef.child("teacher").setValue("Paul");
studentRef.child("userKey").setValue(studentRef.getKey()); <------------
```

Comment: Ok @Nishanth. Thank you. I have added 2 itens more at the question: my method for saving data and the class where is my array ChkList. I just don't know how to insert and save data from this user key as you did (func Save()) and how to call these getuserkey to delete the row. I thank you for any more help

Comment: Hi @Nishanth. First step is ok:  retrieve the 'key` of the user as userKey. But this command line for delete cannot work. I think it is a Swift issue, because it shows me error message even before finish typing `child(students.  )` at this last part: `....child(students.getUserKey.removeValue())`. I will search for more reference now with Swift programmers, but thank you ver much anyway. I have learned a lot with your suggestion trying to make this work.

Comment: I'm really sorry. There is a typo ! Edited my solution.. check now! `child("students").child(students.getUserKey()).removeValue();`

Comment: I'm glad that my suggestions were helpful. You are welcome :)

Comment: I have tried again but what i cannot figure out is how to get, using `students.getUserKey()`, is how to get the userKey for that specific row, selected when I select it.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer moves the Firebase delete behavior behind the scenes so as
>   to not interfere with the normal tableview loading mechanisms. One
>   benefit is reducing the number of calls to Firebase and removing
>   timing issues from the internal tableview animation process.

What worked for me is getting the Firebase stuff out of the way. In my case, I collect all the keys that I want. During the delete, I remove the values from my local object, and when leaving the scene I call my cleanup method from `viewDidDisappear()` to sync the updated data back to Firebase:

```
func syncFavorites() {
    //ref is the leaf for the favorites
    //clear existing
    ref?.removeValue()
    //temp collection
    var faves = [String:Any]()
    //dataArrayKeys is my collection of keys on self
    dataArrayKeys.keys.forEach { (key) in
      faves.updateValue("true", forKey: key)
    }
    ref?.updateChildValues(faves)
  }
```

I handle my `tableview's` delete action using the normal method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
      // Delete the row from the data source
      if let key = dataArr[indexPath.row]["key"] as? String {
        dataArrayKeys.removeValue(forKey: keyToDelete)
        dataArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)
      }
      tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

I have no doubt there is probably a better way. This was the simplest possible thing that worked for me.